# BASH: use . instead of a space for command completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete, function

I have bash function directory located at `/git/function`
This is structure:

```
/git/function/
├── delete
│ ├── delete.dir
│ └── delete.file
├── main.sh
├── get
│├── get.dir.sh
│└── get.file.sh
```

**How to use** `main.sh`

**usage:** get + space + TAB(to autocomplete from `/git/function/get/` directory)
**output:** 
`dir file` 
**Next**: when I select select `get file` it runs script from `/git/function/get/get.file.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Directory where the functions are located
functiondir="/git/function"

# List of supported commands:
commands=(
  "get"
  "delete"
)

# Function to execute the 'get' command
get() {
  echo "Running $functiondir/get/get.$1.sh"
}

# Function to execute the 'delete' command
delete() {
  echo "Running $functiondir/delete/delete.$1.sh"
}

# Autocompletion function for command names
_completion() {
  # Find all files in the specified function directory with the given command name
  local function_files=$(find "$functiondir/$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$1.*.sh" -printf '%f\n' | sed "s/^$1\.//;s/\.sh$//")
  
  # Generate autocompletion options based on the found files
  COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$function_files" -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"))
}

# Set autocompletion for 'get' and 'delete' commands using the _completion function
complete -F _completion -o filenames "${commands[@]}"
```

**I have couple questions:**

- main.sh is sourced from .bashrc
- I want to use <kbd>.</kbd> instead of <kbd>space</kbd> for command completion,
- I need dynamically generate content from sub-dir `/git/function/` without adding additional functions to main.sh
- the fist part of the command for example: if I type <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>  (I should check if `sub-dir` exist and if true then generate content of this directory `/git/function/get` as autocomplete)
- if I type <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> (I should check if `sub-dir` exist and if true then generate content of this directory `/git/function/delete` as autocomplete)

If you know better solution to dynamically load custom functions I will appreciate if you can share some tips

Comment: I am struggling to parse you question. I have tried to improve it, but then realise that I misinterpreted it. So tried again and again. Re-write so that it can be groked with just one reading.

Comment: How are the scripts to be started? If the completion creates e.g. `delete.dir` as a command word, how does the shell find this command? Are the directories in the `$PATH`? Would it be an option to create an alias for each of them?

Comment: so main.sh is sourced from .bashrc. Than in command line you should be able to type get or delete than space and TAB for autocomplete from the mapped folder assigned to the given VERB

Answer (score 0):

The programmable completion character can easily be changed:

```
bind '".":complete'
```

I don't think that this is the way to go here, though.

I guess the better approach is to get all executable files from the hierarchy (or just certain directories like `get` and `delete`) and use this file list as result set for `complete -E # ...` and `complete -I # ...`